# DatabaseHandler.close() - Null pointer exception even if checked

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

My code looks like this:

```
    if (dbHandler != null) dbHandler.close();
```

How is it possible getting a nullPointerException on this line? It looks like I am getting a NPE inside a system functions of SQLite.

Of course there are more similar functions but the basic structure is demonstrated i think. The weird thing is that this happened to one user (at least we dont know about others). The device should be Samsung SII with Android 4.0.4

**EDIT**
Solved by rewriting the databaseHandler, propably there was some more instances hazard.

Comment: What is `dbHandler`? Is this your class?

Comment: @Sam, I didn't see your comment. I just removed mine.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads which access the database? I open my database only in the application class once and never close it.

Comment: DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper. dbHandler is object of DatabaseHandler. And yes, it is used in only one instance and one thread. Is it a good idea to never close a database? Is there any possibility of causing any problem, so i could remove the database close?

Comment: Could you please paste the complete `DatabaseHandler` (if possible correctly formatted, use ctrl + shift + f in eclipse to make sure...) and could you say if `getAllContent()` is part of the `DatabaseHandler` class?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was wondering about the exact same thing (see included code above). It just does not make sense that this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your `dbHandler` object has a reference to a SQLiteDatabase that is null.

Comment: It is possible. But doesnt close() control for null database?      `public synchronized void close() {
        if (mIsInitializing) throw new IllegalStateException("Closed during initialization");

        if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
            mDatabase.close();
            mDatabase = null;
        }
    }`

Comment: Could you include the code for your DatabaseHandler class.

Comment: Please post full stack trace and include details in your  DatabaseHandler class. Leaving out the details doesn't help.

Comment: I left the details because the whole DatabaseHandler is about 5000 lines long. Ill add more about this particualar method and add more of the stacktrace.

Comment: What's in line 2300 and 2613 of your DatabaseHandler class.